# Can we award bounties to questions?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

- Is this a [feature-request](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) worth asking about?
- Is it too difficult to implement a system where questions can be awarded bounties as well?
- Are there any reasons why this should not be done?
- And should this be done on other sites as well?

I think the justification for this is obvious - a lot of questions require as much effort on the part of the asker as the solver.

Related: [Giving puzzle questions the recognition they deserve](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3225/giving-puzzle-questions-the-recognition-they-deserve)

Comment: I wonder if this is a question for Meta.SE?  I don't know the specifics of how the sites work, but this might be something that would need to be implemented across the board, instead of just on Puzzling.SE.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135469/bounty-like-facility-for-rewarding-excellent-questions, in particular the answer by Pacoverflow.

Comment: Side note: If this is implemented, there should probably be a restriction on how much bounty rep can be earned from a single question.

Answer (score 13):

#### Upvote if you think that this feature request should be implemented

---

> Is this a [feature-request](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) worth asking about?

I think yes. There is nothing wrong in asking a feature request. And it seems like this feature request is good for Puzzling SE.

> Is it too difficult to implement a system where questions can be awarded bounties as well?

I have no idea about it. But it was once said that "[The amount of rep that is generated by each action (question up-votes, etc.) is too integral to the system to be a per-site setting.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242718/313472)". But [Stack Apps SE](https://stackapps.com/) have +10 reputation for a single upvote on questions which is definitely different from other SE communities.

> Are there any reasons why this should not be done?

If we talk about Puzzling SE, I don't think that there is any reason of why this should not be done. This feature will encourage good questions. It will also increase the participation on this site.

> And should this be done on other sites as well?

I... don't really think that this needs to be implemented on all the communities. People ask question on other sites because of the some doubt in their mind. They seek answer to their problem. But it is not the case here on Puzzling SE. Questioner who posts puzzles here knows the answer to their puzzle in most of the cases. They aren't really gaining anything by posting puzzles here. They do it selflessly. In fact, in most of the good puzzles, questioner makes more effort in making the puzzle than the one who answers it. But there might be some other communities too who might benefit from this feature.

---

NOTE : This is a very short answer.

Answer (score 6):

In response to the first question (*Is it worth asking about?*), I think it is, and I don't think I'm alone. Here's a few comments I've found on questions showing that there are plenty of people who would like to give more rep/votes/bounties to specific *questions* (and I'm sure it's not exhaustive):

- ["gem of questions wish I could upvote 10 times"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/18679)
- ["Absolutely fantastic question, meticulously constructed, wish I could upvote 20 times!"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/20951)
- ["You, sir, deserve more upvotes!"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/57844)
- ["I wish I could upvote it twice!"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/58938)
- ["Truly a bounty deserving question"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/58995)
- ["I wish I could upvote twice"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/58996)
- ["Wow! Obscure puzzle, but well done! I wish I had more than one upvote!"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/64147)
- ["Amazing puzzle! Well done. Wish I could upvote more!"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/79120)
- ["I wish I could upvote this multiple times! An amazing puzzle!"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/79287)
- ["This is such a well done puzzle, I wish I could spend rep to upvote it more than once"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/84878)
- ["Wish there was some way to give you a bounty for a question"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/91312)
- ["Wish I could upvote more than once!"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/94516)
- ["At times like this, *I* wish a bounty could be awarded to a question."](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/94600)
- ["Deserves more upvotes/views (pity I can't give a bounty to a question)"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/87241) <sup>*</sup>

<sub>* Full disclosure: that last one is my own comment, though it was made before the current reignition of the discussion...</sub>

As for the other questions, they're getting pretty good discussion here: [What is our reason for wanting bounties on questions?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4862/what-is-our-reason-for-wanting-bounties-on-questions)

Comment: +1 Lovely link-list to a lot of very nice puzzles. (*sneak-advertising* - and it actually worked. Got a few more upvotes on some of my puzzles ;c))

Comment: @BmyGuest - lol, didn't really intend it as advertising, but can't say I'm sorry it brought you a few more (well deserved) upvotes. :)