# Very good but forgotten posts

Tags: discussion

I'm sad.

Everyday I can see posts with very low quality or too easy. Others on hold for multiple reasons ... and just a few amazing puzzles. I love seeing a good puzzle, which took a lot of work and effort to build. But as they are not easy, there are no answers, there are no views and eventually are forgotten while easy puzzles made in 5 min get thousands of views and lots of answers or attempts.

Apart from bounties, there should be something to draw attention to them.

Comment: What's wrong with bounties?

Comment: @randal'thor They cost rep? It's the only reason I can think why someone wouldn't want to use one.

Comment: @dcfyj Then I guess we need someone who has more rep than they know what to do with. Hmm ... *looks around* ...

Comment: @rand there is nothing wrong but yet I see only a few

Comment: @randal'thor Note that you can't award bounty to a question.

Comment: May be there can be another tab like "best question of the hour " like hot,active..etc which moderators can maintain which is not based on number of votes/views.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain That's why I think the idea of [wrap-up](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/sample-commentaries-on-puzzle-creation) answers is great.

Comment: Isn't that what up-votes on questions are for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of attempts and ideas to that goal which might be worth re-kindling, if you haven't seen them yet.

Discussions and ideas:

- A [suggested UI hack](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4989/improved-interface-to-posts-of-common-interest) to get a better link to interesting things.
- A discussion about some [automated evaluation algorithm](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4974/should-we-implement-an-automated-way-of-highlighting-quality-content)
- A [discusson on other ways to promote quality](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4862/what-is-our-reason-for-wanting-bounties-on-questions) content
- [curated lists](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4968/should-we-have-a-meta-sorted-list-of-puzzles-here-on-meta)

Search points for quality puzzles:

- The [fortnightly challenges](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/should-we-have-weekly-fortnightly-topic-challenges) series
- Following your [favourite puzzle authors](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja)
- There is a [best-of series](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of) on meta

Comment: I'm so tempted to edit that "favourite puzzle authors" to link to [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5840/bmyguest) instead ...

Comment: @randal'thor ;c)  I think it might be worthwhile to have a meta post on "favorite puzzle authors" in general. I've discussed this a bit with Alconja, who created a nice data-query to that goal as well. (Which if course can't see the link to at the moment. Need to find it again.)

Comment: Not sure if I'd agree with that idea - it sounds a bit like ego-stroking, and might cause an 'in-crowd' effect with people who don't get on the list feeling miffed. Plus SE is supposed to be all about focusing on content, not people.

Comment: @randal'thor I partly agree. That's why I thought some objectivly created list via data-query would do nicely. Currenlty you can only look at "rep" which, as we all agree (?), gives a very distorted picture as far as puzzle-posting is concerned. A properly automated query would (maybe) provide a kind of objective "high score" list for *authors* not *solvers*. Just maybe. Still looking for the data. (Was in a chat.)

Comment: I created [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/445681) a while ago, which doesn't quite do what you're asking, but I do see a lot of active, quality contributors near the top of the list.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain That's no use for top *askers* though. I see Gareth, f'', McMagister, q_a, Joel Rondeau, M Oehm all up there near the top, all of whom have asked hardly any questions, often even *none*.

Comment: @randal'thor [How's this](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/539456), then?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Can you set a threshold for minimum number of questions asked? People who've hardly ever asked any questions still dominate the top bunch.

Comment: @randal'thor Turned out to be a little trickier than I thought.  [Try this](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/539456).

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain - [Here's the one](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/513491/popular-puzzle-creators) BmyGuest is referring to above... tries to rate users by consistent "quality" - i.e. takes into account votes & votes/view, averaged across all questions posted by that user (filters out users with <5 questions to avoid outliers)

Comment: i didnt know about the query tool. is very interesting!

Comment: @randal'thor, when I run GPR's query (the one you say you see me near the top of) I don't see myself in the output at all. (I see it's been edited recently; perhaps that's why.)

Comment: @Gareth Yep, GPR must have edited it again after my comment.

Comment: I'll just leave [this here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/64/revival) and [this over here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer)