# Puzzle gallery via comments

Tags: discussion

This question is meant to serve as a trouble-free gallery of puzzles
deemed noteworthy by anyone.

Whoever wants to contribute,
feel free to post a minimalistic answer,
something like the following,
and add **comments** that link to any puzzles for whatever reasons.

> **Puzzle gallery comments from [[you]](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users)**
>
> <sub>(Nobody else comment here, please,
>     instead post your own ***Puzzle gallery comments from [you]***
>     answer like this.)</sub>

These answers are expected to remain **unedited** once posted.
 
Rather, this gallery is meant to function **purely through comments**
under such posts.

- Revisions, being mere additions and deletions of comments,
  **will not interrupt Meta Puzzling’s list of active questions**.
- Over-generosity will be tucked away automatically by
  “show _ more comments.”
- Each answer is expected to have **comments only from its poster**.
  If a poster becomes frustrated by interloping comments,
  they can delete the existing post and start a new answer with just
  their own comments.
- The resulting gallery is self-curated, post by poster,
  and requires no consensus or bickering.
- We can find out about otherwise-overlooked puzzles
  from users whose interests overlap.
- Self-promotion is possible
  without a sense of guilt or a pretense of objectivity.
- (Incidental benefit:  Any poster can test-format
  comments ultimately meant elsewhere,
  as nobody will be notified of
  temporary comments under a poster’s own post here.)

Related meta posts:

[Should we have a meta-sorted list of puzzles here on Meta?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4968/should-we-have-a-meta-sorted-list-of-puzzles-here-on-meta)

[Should we implement an automated way of highlighting quality content?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4974)

Comment: I quite like this idea, but I feel it may get messy, if many answer. And also, what is the purpose of this?

Comment: The messier the merrier! (Lack of central control might be worthwhile just for averting a choke point.) With minimal disruption of the active-question list, this can serve as a low-profile resource, and outlet, for those who are interested.

Comment: Has this been discussed anywhere on meta before? If not, it might be helpful/necessary, both to make sure it's something people want, and to give people space & time to provide feedback on how it will work.

Comment: Aw, @Emrakul, I was enthusiastic about your comment when all it asked was
"Has this been discussed anywhere on meta before?,"
which is quite an interesting question over all SE sites
(I didn't find any evidence of it here or on Meta SE.)
But if people don't like this approach,
all they have to do is ignore it.
This is meant to be unobtrusively voluntary
and carry no official weight.
Any constructive ideas can well be shared in these comments
to the question post, or added to the question post itself,
or - better yet - can be demonstrated by example.

Comment: Missed that post in February, but like the idea. Essentially an open, self-controlled favorites list. Until something like this (or better) is provided by the SE, I throw my hat in the ring and will start using it.

Comment: Thank you for jumping in, @BmyGuest! (I ^voted and canceled because, at least for now, this might work best unjudged.)

Answer (score 1):

#### Puzzle gallery comments from [humn](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18129/humn)

<sub>(Nobody else comment here, please,
 feel free to post your own ***Puzzle gallery comments from [you]***
 answer like this.)</sub>

Comment: Long-unsolved puzzles with tantalizing components:
[What is going on? Paintings too?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36249/what-is-going-on-paintings-too)
/
[A Strange Correspondence](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32640/a-strange-correspondence)

Comment: [Linked word squares](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36044/linked-word-squares)
- A kind of puzzle I would like to encounter in a newspaper

Comment: [Bearing due, due and back](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/26227/bearing-due-due-and-back)
- Wish I had a program that can make a picture
  to show off how interesting the solution is

Comment: [3 gates and a drop of acid](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48425/3-gates-and-a-drop-of-acid)
- A perfect detective-story [`circuitry`](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circuitry) morsel

Comment: [_Mi, So, Re, Do?_](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49303/mi-so-re-do)
- Play the MIDI file to hear how good a puzzle can sound

Comment: [Dragons: Myth or MathJax?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40338/dragons-myth-or-mathjax)
-  ...or is it mathematics?  Is it art?
`Spoiler: Yes and yes!`
It's also
[a gallery of mind-blowing **math**terpieces](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/40370/18129)
by none other than
[our visiting MathJax titan](http://stackexchange.com/users/235490/davide-cervone).
How about
[this quick-click sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q54N5.png)?!

Comment: [A simple nonogram](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49666/a-simple-nonogram)
- A recursively defined puzzle I wish I'd thought up

Comment: Puzzles worth printing, cutting out, and solving by hand -
[Ten suspicious coasters](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/35855/ten-suspicious-coasters)
/
[The Hyper-Modern Kidnapper: Crime Scene #3](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50057/the-hyper-modern-kidnapper-crime-scene-3)
/
(More for amusement:)
[Physical puzzle in four parts](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5578/physical-puzzle-in-four-parts)

Comment: [The impossible digital sum](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53684/the-impossible-digital-sum)
- A tight pixelated relative of alphametics.
The minimalistic regularity of the bottom row (sum)
shows just how much care this puzzle took to work out.

Comment: $\raise-5.2mu{\Huge\color{#aea}\bullet}
 \llap{\large\color{#7a7}\bigcirc}
 \llap{\large\color{#090}\checkmark} ~$
This is what I get too

Answer (score 1):

#### Puzzle gallery comments from [manshu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17482/manshu)

<sub>(Nobody else comment here, please,
 feel free to post your own ***Puzzle gallery comments from [you]***
 answer like this.)</sub>

Comment: [Rainbow Road Rabbit Hole](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24792/rainbow-road-rabbit-hole): Even though I can't understand how this mega puzzle is solved, I find that concept of adding one puzzle into another very intriguing.

Comment: [Find the letters that complete these five patterns](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6138/find-the-letters-that-complete-these-five-patterns): This is 'the best' pattern puzzle I have ever seen. The answer feels correct when you find it. It even that aw-moment.

Answer (score 1):

#### Puzzle gallery comments from [BmyGuest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5840/bmyguest)

<sub>(Nobody else comment here, please,
 feel free to post your own ***Puzzle gallery comments from [you]***
 answer like this.)</sub>

Comment: [Ernie and...](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1631/penguino): All the puzzles of Penguino are an inspiration and should not be missed.

Comment: [REJBÄS - an unfinished flat-pack puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43276/rejb%c3%84s-an-unfinished-flat-pack-puzzle): Simply one of my favorite puzzles as far as style and presentation is concerned. Without any direct referenecs, everybody knows what inspired this puzzle design. The puzzle itself is not bad, but neither is it [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja)'s best. That honor goes to [Rube-Wordberg-Machine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33523/the-rube-wordberg-machine) .

Answer (score 1):

#### Puzzle gallery comments from [LeppyR64](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1777/leppyr64)

<sub>(Nobody else comment here, please,
 feel free to post your own ***Puzzle gallery comments from [you]***
 answer like this.)</sub>